# python : converting Unicode to float with decimal precision

Tags: python, unicode, floating

I would like to convert the unicode string to float with 2 decimal places. I am using locale.atof() to covert to float. I know that we can use locale.format to format the resulting value to 2 decimal points. Is it possible to use a single function to convert from unicode to float with decimal precision specified ?

Currently i am using it like this

```
float(locale.format('%.2f',(locale.atof('3.145678')))
```

Is there any other way ?

Comment: Where is your example?

Comment: locate.atof('3.145677777'). I need the output to be 3.14. Curently i am doing it this way. 
 float(locale.format('%.2f',(locale.atof(i[3])*100)/snpdbtm))

Comment: A `float` doesn't have a specifiable number of decimal points. If your value is a string, you can choose the number of decimal points; if it's a float, you cannot. If anything you're asking how to trim a string containing a numeric value to a given number of decimal places; floats needn't enter the picture at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `round` function rounds to the number of places specified, but there isn't one function that both converts a string and rounds.

```
>>> round(float('3.141592'),2)
3.14
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module, which offers utils to deal with floating point precision, e.g.:

```
from decimal import Decimal as D
from decimal import ROUND_DOWN

d = D('3.145677777').quantize(D('0.01'))  
print(d)
# 3.15
```

You can set the rounding behaviour as well if you want to truncate:

```
d = D('3.145677777').quantize(D('0.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
print(d)
# 3.14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float(("%.2f"%float('3.145')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your own one function:

```
def trim_decimal_points(s):
    result = float(s)
    return format(result, '.2f')
```

Then use it as one function:

```
trim_decimal_points('3.145677777')
```